# How to set each value in a current_group() to its absolute value before summing the group?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT file that sets up a group. I want to sum one of the fields that are in the group but I would like all of the the negative numbers in the grouping to be positive before summing.

I tried using the abs() and translate functions on the current-group()/Transaction_Credit_Amount field but an get an error. The errors say that a sequence of one or more than one item is not allowed as the first argument to translate() or abs().

Here is the original line of code I am trying to change so that all of the Transaction_Credit_Amount values are positive before summing.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(current-group()/Transaction_Credit_Amount,'-',''), '#0.#############')"/>
```

The expected result is the summation of the absolute values of all Transaction_Credit_Amount values.

Comment: You haven't told us what you did to trigger the error, but a typical error to trigger that message would be to write `abs(current-group()/@x)` in place of `current-group()/@x/abs(.)`. Functions like `abs` only apply to single items, to to sequences of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `current-group()/Transaction_Credit_Amount/abs(.)` to get a sequence of numbers of the absolute values and of course you can then sum them with `sum(current-group()/Transaction_Credit_Amount/abs(.))`.